# C# ASP.NET cs0246 issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having an issue where I keep getting error message CS0246 on my web server, but not in my visual studio environment. The issue is coming from a dll I reference in my project. The server cannot find my namespace for my dll.

To solve this I tried copying every file in my project directory to my web server, adding a  tag in my web.config file, and adding an import statement in my aspx page. I have also tried adding an assembly reference in my aspx page, but that seems to require a change in the registry which I don't think I have access to.

I should also note my dll and namespace name are different, but changing the names of either did nothing. I also completely removed the dll and copied the code files directly into my project, but it still could not find the namespace.

I thus think I'm supposed to register the namespace and dll somewhere else, but I cannot figure out where. Any help will be appreciated.

If it matters, both my web project and dll are using .NET2.0

Comment: Was the DLL originally in the `bin` directory of the web site?

Comment: The DLL is in there now. In my Visual Studio Project the reference is the actual project. I have tried referencing the actual DLL from different places to no avail.

Comment: Did you resolve this problem? Please check out my answer below if it could help you. If so, please mark it as correct to help next readers.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is the equivalent of the annoying "did you reboot", but have you tried making a new solution and re-adding the projects and references? Sometimes the .sln file can get corrupted.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't tried that, but I just did and it didn't fix anything. I also tried recreating the project and it didn't fix anything.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the web.config file contains instructions for the .NET framework to generate temporary files.

Please check your config file for something similar to:

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host
      factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="YourNamespace.ShouldBeCorrect.Here" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

This is likely the case if your error page contains a reference to a dynamically generated file such as:

```
Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\133f2363\4ba6d0ba\App_Web_index.cshtml.a8d08dba.ociepbng.0.cs    Line: 27
```